# Replacing/reloading input list with jQuery and leaving first element

Tags: javascript, jquery, reload, html-lists

I created jQuery function that gets bunch of simple objects that contains `id` and `title`.

Then I run simple loop to create list:

```
$.each(data['results'], function(key, val) {
    items.push('<label for="radio_show_' + val['id'] + '" >' 
        + '<input type="checkbox" name="radio_show" class="checkbox" id="radio_show_' + val['id'] + '" value="'+ val['id'] + '" >'
        + val['title'] 
        + '</label>');
});
```

But now I don't know how to do the cleaning part.

I want to append this list to certain `<ul>`, I could do that with `.appendTo()`, but each time i would call this, it would add more and more lists. So before appending I would need to delete `<ul>` contains with `.empty()`. But the main problem is that I want to keep first element that would be same input just with no value and title of "Select all" (You get the idea).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you use something like this to 'clear' the `ul` -

```
$("ul > li:not(:first)").remove()
```

That should remove all the items in the `ul` aprt from the first one.

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/zUuE9/

Answer (score 0):

You could clear your `ul` with:

```
$('#my_ul input[value!=""]').parent('li').remove();
```

This would leave your Select All Checkbox (value="")  in the `ul`.

Answer (score 0):

To remove all li's except for the first one, try this:

```
$('#my-ul li').slice(1).remove();
```